# R bnlearn package error reassigning conditional probabilities

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I am using the package bnlearn in R to construct a custom fitted, discrete Bayesian network using both data and expert knowledge. http://www.bnlearn.com/examples/custom/

This entails creating a bn.fit object using bn.fit() and  modifying the local distributions of the nodes of interest. For discrete Bayesian networks (or discrete nodes in conditional Gaussian networks) the conditional probability table can be extracted from the bn.fit object with coef(), updated, and re-saved.

```
library(bnlearn)
dag = model2network("[A][C][F][B|A][D|A:C][E|B:F]")  #creates a network
fitted <- bn.fit(dag, learning.test) #(determines conditional probability 
given data in learning.test)
fitted[[3]]  #CP for node [C] as example, fitted$C also works 
cpt <- coef(fitted[[3]]) #extract coefficients from table
cpt[1:length(cpt)] = c(0.50, 0.25, 0.25)  #new CPs
fitted$C<-cpt #assign new CPs to joint CP table
fitted$C #Works

Parameters of node C (multinomial distribution)

Conditional probability table:
a    b    c 
0.50 0.25 0.25
```

I would like to update a large number of nodes by indexing the bn.fit object, i.e.

```
fitted[[3]][[4]][1:3]<-cpt  #returns error
fitted[[3]][[4]]<-cpt       #returns error

Error in check.nodes(name, x) : 
nodes must be a vector of character strings, the labels of the nodes.
```

Given the equivalence between [[ and $ operators, can anyone explain why this is the case and a potential work around.

```
identical(fitted$C,fitted[[3]])
TRUE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Due to the final line of your example showing that the objects are identical, it suggests that dispatch methods for `$<-` and `[[<-` may be different or not actually defined, however, that's not quite what happens here.

The relevant function for the line `fitted$C<-cpt` is `bnlearn:::'$<-.bn.fit'`. Looking at the code for this leads to
`bnlearn:::'[[<-.bn.fit'`. So there are methods defined for both `[[` and `$`. 
 Again looking at the code, leads to `bnlearn:::check.nodes`, and a quick read of this last function shows that you need to pass a `character` to the `name` argument of `bnlearn:::'[[<-.bn.fit'`, and it needs to be in the set of node names in the graph.  Hence why `fitted[[3]] <- cpt`, and `fitted[[3]][[4]]<-cpt`, and other iterations don't work (as you are passing `3`, which is neither `character` nor a node name.

As an alternative, if you can change your workflow slightly, you could use `fitted[["C"]] <- cpt`, which will be safer than passing by index. If you do want to pass by index, you could extract the cpd nodes name by the indexing.

Comment: Love and respect if anyone can work out how to add the backticks , rather than single quotes in the `bnlearn:::` functions .

Comment: Thanks.  Extracting the node names by indexing the bn.fit object worked.    
    fitted[[fitted[[3]][[1]]]]<-cpt

Comment: you're welcome. You could probably tidy it up a bit by say using `nms <- names(fitted)` and then using the index on that `fitted[[ nms[3] ]] <- cpt`